# nginx rewrite based on variable regex location

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I'm moving an existing website and going from Litespeed (Apache .htaccess) to Nginx and I'm having trouble converting a particular regex rewrite that is critical to the functionality of the site. The previous .htaccess rewrites simply take any /word not previously matched to a specific rule and convert that to a parameter on the index.php.

Prior .htaccess rules example:

```
RewriteRule ^report$ index.php?page=report&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)$ index.php?page=browser&region=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/([0-9{4}]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)$ index.php?page=program&region=$1&program=$3&year=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

So if /report was the URL, it would load the report page, otherwise if it was /arizona then it would load the browser page with region=arizona, and so on.

My current nginx location rules

```
        location /report {
            rewrite (?i)^/report$ /index.php?page=report&$query_string last;
        }

        location ^/([a-z0-9\-\_]+)$ {
            rewrite (?i)^/([a-z0-9\-\_]+)$ /index.php?page=browser&region=$1 last;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
```

Both the home page (nothing in URL) and /report work fine. Also if I manually add /index.php?page=browser&region=arizona then it works fine as well.

However, entering /arizona results in the index downloading rather than being processed by php-fpm. I've tried all sorts of searches and suggestions for the regex resulting in either it not being matched or simply downloading the index.

Comment: The second `location` is missing the `~` or `~*` operator to indicate a regular expression.

Comment: I had tried that previously with the same result but not sure I had the format correct. I did `location ~* ^/([a-z0-9\-\_]+)$ {` but it still resulted in only downloading the index. Also it seems to be identifying the /arizona because taking out that /location block it gives a 404.

Comment: You used `rewrite...last` and not `rewrite...break`? The latter would definitely download `index.php` whereas the former should execute it as normal.

Comment: Yep, it's definitely last as it needs to re-loop for index.php. The /report is working fine for the last reloop.

Comment: So it looks like your original suggestion actually fixed the issue but Chrome was giving false responses. Postman tests fine as does another PC and browser. I'm reworking other issues now with the parameter content not being passed for region=.